# Loop through a scalar of temp tables and drop what exists in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have `stored procedure` in `SQL Server 2008` that utilizes quite a few temp tables (I'm refactoring another's code and am trying to move these to scalars, but that's a longer process).  At the beginning of the  stored procedure, I want to declare all the temp tables, then loop through them and drop any temp table that exists.

Utilizing other programing langues (such as `python`), you could create a `for loop` and loop through the variables.  Can you do this in `SQL Server`?  `WHILE` seems like the correct function to use, but every example I've seen uses an incremental value, such as `SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1`.  I am not trying to increment, just take ever value and check to see if the temp table exists - if it does, drop it.  If it does not, next value.

Here is what I imagined, but am not sure what to do next, nor if it's even possible to drop tables programmatically:

```
DECLARE @Tables table (tablename varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @Tables VALUES 
    ('#a'),
    ('#b'),
    ('#c'),
    ('#d');

-- this part is how I would write the code in python -- 

for i in @Tables:
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..+ i ') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE i
```

Is there a way to accomplish this inside of my `stored procedure`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop without cursor.
It's just necessary to add IDENTITY column in table variable

```
DECLARE @Tables table (Id int IDENTITY, tablename varchar(50)
INSERT INTO @Tables VALUES
    ('#a'),
    ('#b'),
    ('#c'),
    ('#d');

DECLARE @Id int = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM @Tables),
        @dsql nvarchar(max)
WHILE (@Id IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN 
  SELECT @dsql = 'IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb.dbo.' + tablename + ''') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ' + tablename
  FROM @Tables
  WHERE Id = @Id
  EXEC sp_executesql @dsql
SELECT @Id = MIN(Id) FROM @Tables WHERE Id > @Id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) for that, for example:

```
DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(50)
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT tablename
FROM @Tables;

OPEN table_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor 
INTO @tablename

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @tablename
            -- Your DROP TABLE code goes here

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor 
    INTO @tablename
END 
CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
```